# Fullcalendar refresh on other displays

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to use the full-calendar on some displays in several rooms , if there is change anything I want to show it live "without page reload"  how is it possible to do that easily ?
I don't want use any Browser-Plugins or something for time-setting - should be live !

Answer (score 1):

You can refetch the events after certain intervals, something like below:

```
$(function () { setInterval(function () {     $('#MyCalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')}, 1000);//set the milliseconds which will trigger continuously   });
```

Comment: thx, bu in which file should i  input this code ?   In the main-room is a display where i can change the events with touchscreen. Should i make an extra page for the displays in other rooms , including your code ?

Comment: Call this function after fullcalendar method.